# Can VTD-XML's index be without reading file into memory

Tags: xml, vtd-xml

I need to do random access on a set of XML files on memory-bound & cpu-bound devices (e.g mobile). I've read what I could on VTD-XML but there seems to be very little info on the indexing capability.

Am I right in thinking I could:
a- Index on computer/device A
b- Copy index over to a different computer/device
c- Use the index to access a small fragment of the XML (without having to read the whole XML into memory)

Then I can use the small XML fragment and apply any kind of transformation I like (e.g XSLT, etc. as I would a normal XML fragment).

2ndly, I read one post that suggested the VTD-XML format is platform-dependent. Can someone confirm that is the case.

Cheers

Chris

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In general, you should read XML in memory along with index to make the whole thing work. However, if you extract the fragment and do any post processing, you could garbage collect the original XML data since it is no longer needed.

I can confirm that it is platform independent.